# Aplicação PHP setar impressora do cliente?

Tags: php, impressora

Bom dia!
Estou prestes a iniciar um novo projeto PHP e logo no documento de requisitos, vi que uma das etapas de um ciclo de atividades consiste em setar a impressora a qual o cliente (dispositivo móvel) irá fazer impressões.

Até onde percebo, o PHP por ser uma linguagem que roda no lado servidor, não tem acesso às configurações do cliente. E que poderia sim fazer impressão, mas apenas à impressoja já conectada ao dispositivo.

Comentei isso com o gerente de projetos e disse que não seria possível fazer (ao menos não com PHP). 
Mesmo explicando o que foi aqui escrito, o mesmo insistiu que sim, que da pra fazer e me pediu pra investigar mais à fundo.

Alguém sabe se existe essa possibilidade?
Obrigado desde já.

Comment: Apesar da sua pergunta estar meio fora do escopo do site ou até insuficiente de exemplos. Mas já vi sistema que usa um "serviço" instalado na máquina cliente onde está a impressora, configura a impressora nele, criando um "ponto de impressão", e aí é só sua aplicação direcionar para o IP que está esse serviço. Ou se já tem uma impressora IP, aí faz direto a requisição. (isso é o que já vi, seria bom pesquisar mais)

Comment: Não, PHP é errado para quase todas aplicações que as pessoas estão tentando fazer com ele, ele foi feito para fazer sites, nada mais que isto. Dá para fazer gambiarras, mas não como PHP (até dá pra fazer com PHP, mas aí a gambiarra seria enorme porque teria que instalar o PHP na máquina, e é justamente por não ter que instalar nada que as pessoas fazem web.

Comment: Será que o seu gerente de projetos não está confundindo php com pearl?

Comment: Pois é, @AugustoVasques. Percebe-se que ele não tem muita noção do que se pode fazer com PHP.